# Changing existing array in a method, C++ style?

Tags: c++

Is there a more "C++ style" of writing a method that changes existing array?

```
void Util::sevenColors( const float* color1, float* color2 , unsigned int size )
{
    for( unsigned int i=0; i<size; i++ )
    {
       color2[i] = color1[i] * 7.0f; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The "C++ style" should be use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @songyuanyao,  please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to avoid a raw loop, can be more c++-y

```
void Util::sevenColors( const float* color1, float* color2 , unsigned int size )
{
    std::transform(color1, color1 + size, color2,
                   [](float in) { return 7.0f * in;} );
}
```

And if that memory is dynamically managed, consider using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.